# Create a grid from a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, vector-grid

I have a shapefile which looks like this (this is a snippet of it):

[image: pre-grid shapefile]

I would like to create a grid in a new shapefile which will be overlaid (that's not a technical term, I'm just not sure how to describe it) on this map.

The grid should be comprised of equal sized polygons, except by the borders where they can (and in all likelihood will) be smaller. It should look like this:

[image: post-grid shapefile]

I have tried using the Create Fishnet tool in ArcMap to accomplish this, but this gives me a grid which is always rectangular and does not stop at the borders of the original shapefile.

How do I create this shapefile?